# Keep Scroll Positioning in nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a long list of products on page A that I am scrolling through. When I choose one product to visit the details about it then click back button API call happened and show product from the first one. how can I prevent this action and stays at the scroll position where I left. by the way I am using nuxt

Comment: Hi, could you please add more details on what you tried and give us more context? A [repro] could also be a good idea.

Comment: I tried indexeddb to save products detail on client storage then when they want to go back dont have to call API,and with scrollIntoView event in js scroll into that product.BUT its not the right answer

Comment: Please show us some code. Hard to debug without it.